# what is differences between $('element , #id') and $('element', '#id') in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know **$('element, #id')** selects all **elements** & **#id**.
But what does do **$('element', '#id')** !? 
I only know they aren't similar. So what's difference?

Comment: I think you mean `$('element, #id')` for the first one

Comment: Yes, I am really sorry :| and thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('element, #id')` - it is [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) where all elements with given tagname and element with given id will be selected

```js
$('span, #myid').addClass('myclass');//all spans and the myid element is selected
```

```css
.myclass {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
}
#myid.myclass {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>
<p>
  <span>2</span>
</p>
<div id="myid">
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

`$('element', '#id')` - is [context based](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) search, ie it will find all elements with given tagName which are descendants of an element with given ID

```js
$('span', '#myid').addClass('myclass'); //only span elements under myid is selected
```

```css
.myclass {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
}
#myid.myclass {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1</span>
<p>
  <span>2</span>
</p>
<div id="myid">
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```